# Javascript numberguessing game, get get inner html on new lines

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

So I created a number guessing game, where you are to guess a number from 1 to 10. It works fine, except that I want the hints that show up on the bottom of the div, are to stay there and then for the next hint to come up on a new line below the last hint. As far as I know, you cannot just write several lines within one ID?

```
<body>
<div id="mainCont">
        <h1>Guess a number between 1 and 10</h1>

    <p>Number:
        <input type="text" id="numberGuess">
        <input type="button" onclick="guessNum();" value="Guess">
    </p>
    <div id="hint"></div>
</div>
```

```
#mainCont {
width: 500px;
background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
border: solid 2px rgb(200, 200, 200);
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

function guessNum() {
var guess = document.getElementById("numberGuess").value;

if (guess == randomNum) {
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "<p>" + guess + " is correct! :)</p>";
}

if (guess < randomNum) {
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "<p>" + guess + " is too low</p>";
}

if (guess > randomNum) {
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "<p>" + guess + " is to high</p>";
}
```

}

Comment: `+=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML += yourHint + "<br>";
```

In order to add to the current innerHTML. I used the "< br >" because I think that looks nicer than "< p >".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `+=` to answer your question, you should use `else if` to reduce (the likelihood of) checks.

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

function guessNum() {
    var guess = document.getElementById("numberGuess").value;

    if (guess == randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML += "<p>" + guess + " is correct! :)</p>";
    } else if (guess < randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML += "<p>" + guess + " is too low</p>";
    } else if (guess > randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML += "<p>" + guess + " is to high</p>";
    }
}
```